# Python condition not applying (if/elif)

Tags: python, runtime-error, conditional-statements

I have a problem with a condition in my python code.
It's a mathematics application, and here's the part of the code that is not working well:

```
def askNumber():
    """Asks the number to test"""
    a=raw_input("Select the number to test (type 'exit' for leaving):")
    if len(a)!=0 and a.lower!="exit":
        try:
            b= int(a)
            processing(b)
        except ValueError:
            print "Your input is not valid. Please enter a 'number'!"
            time.sleep(1)
            askNumber()
    elif len(a)!=0 and a.lower=="exit":
        answer()
    else:
        print "Your input can't be 'empty'"
        time.sleep(1)
        askNumber()
```

So, when in the raw_input for "a" I type "exit", the supposed condition to apply is the **elif** one but ends up applying the **if** one, ending up printing "Your input is not valid. Please enter a 'number'!" Sorry, if it's something obvious, I'm a begginer, although I tried to find the mistake several times.

Comment: thanks, solved. it was the "a.lower()" issue. What a obvious mistake after all...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need to *call* the `.lower()` function.

```
if len(a) != 0 and a.lower() != "exit":
    # ...
elif len(a) != 0 and a.lower() == "exit":
```

There is no real need to test for `len(a)!=0`, simply test for `a` itself:

```
if a and a.lower() != "exit":
    # ...
elif a and a.lower() == "exit":
```

Empty strings evaluate to `False` in a boolean context.

Answer (score 3):

Your program flow is a bit inside out, may I suggest some improvements?

```
def askNumber():
    """Asks the number to test"""

    while True:
        a = raw_input("Select the number to test (type 'exit' for leaving):")

        if not a:
            print "Your input can't be 'empty'"
            continue

        if a.lower() == "exit":
            answer()
            break

        try:
            b = int(a)
        except ValueError:
            print "Your input is not valid. Please enter a 'number'!"
            continue

        processing(b)
```

Actually, the `not a` branch can be eliminated as well (empty inputs will be handled in `except`).

Comment: thank's a lot for you suggestions. I had no idea of some improvements you suggested could be done. I will try that. Still have to learn about those "break" and "continue" commands...

Answer (score 1):

You could change the condition for the following one:

```
   if a and a.lower() !="exit":
  # .....
   elif a and a.lower() == "exit":
      answer()
   elif a and not a.isdigit(): print "invalid input"
   else:
   #.............
```

Please note that yo don't need `len(a) != 0` , just by using `a` will evaluate if it's empty or not.